# Generate python class from dictionaries

Tags: python

How can I generate python classes from dictionaries?

```py
class TdObject(object):
    pass


def ClassFactory(js_obj, BaseClass=TdObject): # js_obj is actually a dict
    newclass = BaseClass
    if isinstance(js_obj, dict):
        setattr(newclass, '__name__', js_obj['@type'])
        for k, v in js_obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                newcls_ = ClassFactory(v)
            else:
                newcls_ = v
            setattr(newclass, k, newcls_)
    print(newclass.__name__)
```

Everything works well until I added the lines to also translate the dict values from the dictionaries to their own classes. My code just stopped without any errors what so ever.

Here is an example of js_obj

````
{'@type': 'message',
 'author_signature': '',
 'can_be_deleted_for_all_users': True,
 'can_be_deleted_only_for_self': True,
 'can_be_edited': False,
 'can_be_forwarded': True,
 'chat_id': 416195206,
 'contains_unread_mention': False,
 'content': {'@type': 'messageText',
             'text': {'@type': 'formattedText', 'entities': [], 'text': 'Hello World'}},
 'date': 1577954356,
 'edit_date': 0,
 'id': 1827667968,
 'is_channel_post': False,
 'is_outgoing': False,
 'media_album_id': '0',
 'reply_to_message_id': 0,
 'sender_user_id': 416195206,
 'ttl': 0,
 'ttl_expires_in': 0.0,
 'via_bot_user_id': 0,
 'views': 0}```
````

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of `js_obj` that produces the problem?

Comment: Not right now, tomorrow I will be able to. They are basically tdlib json responses tho

Comment: You should probably make a copy of the `BaseClass` and not use `TdObject` as its default value because classes are mutable.

Comment: `newclass`  should probably be an *instance* of `BaseClass`, not the class itself: `newobj = BaseClass()`.

Comment: I added an example of js_obj @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing classes and objects here. The values of attributes would typically be instances of classes, i.e. objects, not classes themselves. That's why things break if you set the value of the attributes you're creating to classes.

If you're actually just looking to create an object from a dictionary (and not a class which you can then use to instantiate multiple objects), something like this works:

```
class FromDict:
    def __init__(self, dct):
        for key in dct:
            setattr(self, key,
                    dct[key] if not isinstance(dct[key], dict) else FromDict(dct[key]))
```

If you do need a class factory, you'll need more code to properly instantiate the objects that need to be assigned as attribute values. You could generate setters for each of those and generate more inner classes in your new class, but I doubt that will be very useful and is a bit more to cover than a simple answer here warrants.